# yAxis data overflows onto chart when positioned right

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I'd like the yAxis labels not to overflow, and also not to overlay on top of the plotted chart.  As you can see from the example, they do:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        marginBottom: 80
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    yAxis: {
            title: {
        text: ''
        },
          opposite: true,
        labels: {
            align: 'right'

        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [209.9, 71.5, 106.4, 1209.2, 1404.0, 1706.0, 135.6, 1408.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uo6shmuL/

I've tried different positioning but I can't see to figure it out without manually setting offsets and padding, which doesn't work because my data is dynamic. How do I get this similar highstocks example to work, where the yAxis is outside of the chart, but nothing is overflowing outside the div?

What I need:

http://jsfiddle.net/P8hrN/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
labels: {
    align: 'left'     
}
```

Comment: This will work, I posted a simpler set of chart config data and what ended up being my problem was this AND some margins set in my chart object